# Why does initializer-list have different result compared with expression-list

Tags: c++, constructor, initializer-list

I feel weird when I write some code below. I am looking forward to the same output, but it turns out to be wrong. Why do the 2 statements have the different output, and what's the difference between (expression-list) and {initializer-list}?

```
cout << string(4, 'c') << endl;  
cout << string{ 4, 'c' } << endl;
```

the output is:

```
cccc  
c   //a square '' before 'c'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization):

> Otherwise, the constructors of `T` are considered, in two phases:
>
> - All constructors that take `std::initializer_list` as the only argument, or as the first argument if the remaining arguments have default values, are examined, and matched by overload resolution against a single argument of type `std::initializer_list`
> - If the previous stage does not produce a match, all constructors of `T` participate in overload resolution against the set of arguments that consists of the elements of the *braced-init-list*, with the restriction that only non-narrowing conversions are allowed. If this stage produces an explicit constructor as the best match for a *copy-list-initialization*, compilation fails (note, in simple *copy-initialization*, explicit constructors are not considered at all).

In your case

```
string(4, 'c')
```

uses the following constructor.

```
std::string(size_type count, 
            char ch, 
            const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

On the other hand,

```
string{ 4, 'c' }
```

uses the following constructor.

```
std::string(std::initializer_list<char> ilist, 
            const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

Had the second constructor not been defined in `std::string`, both of those would have produced identical objects.

Answer (score 4):

Both are [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) calls, but they call two different constructors. The first call ("2" in the link) constructs with a count of chars, hence you get 4 'c's in your case.

The second constructor ("9" in the link) takes a `std::initializer_list`. When you construct using braces instead of parens, *if* the class has a constructor taking an initializer_list it will always take precedence.

If it's any consolation, this behaviour has stumped a *lot* of programmers over the years...